# Perform directory check in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am looking for a way to run a server script that will check that all the required directories are present in the server directory.

I have looked into server.on('event') however, there seems that such event does not exist.

Comment: Have you tried 'fs' lib? It has several methods to check uif a file ou a folder exists... https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: I have been using the fs lib in other parts of my webapp however, I want to be able to run a script as a first thing when the server starts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Node's [`fs.stat`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) function to check if a file exists and `stats.isDirectory()` to check if it's a directory.